# Background Image not scaling in td

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I am on a team trying to convert our Flash Application into HTML5 and Css, and I am running into a bug affecting WebKit and wanted some help trying to figure it out.  The basic idea is that there is a table with a single cell with a background image and a background color and for whatever reason when the image is exactly the right size `background-size: 100% 100%` the image actually shrinks to reveal the background color. This also repeats if I use pixel values instead of % values.

Before anyone tells me to just use a div (since its only one cell anyway), this content is authored by other people who are using an existing tool to create a custom xml document that gives us tables and I have to get my solution to work on the pre-existing content we already have.

This is the fiddle which shows it and follows are image in various browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/CEvnx/2/

**Flash (Reference)**

[image: Flash (reference image)]

**Firefox (working)**

[image: Firefox]

**Chrome (the image shrinks)**

[image: Chrome]

**Safari (the image grows)**

[image: Safari]

P.S. Ignore the height and font differences as those aren't in any way relevant to the problem.

Comment: Why are you setting a width of 300px on the table and a width of 280px on the element? I think if you were to just set the width on the td element alone you would get a result similar to your flash reference

Comment: The main reason is that the custom xml format we were using had that set, this html/css was auto-generated by server-side code.  However if you remove the width from the table and set the td width to 290px you get the exact same problem http://jsfiddle.net/CEvnx/8/.

Answer (score 0):

has to do with the table's `border-width`, if you set `border-width` at `2px` or less the background sizes correct (in Chrome/Safari).  Quite strange that Chrome shrinks and Safari grows.  There must be some odd math or image resize logic in webkit and probably worth submitting a [bug report](http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html).

Comment: Yea, also if you change the size a little bit the same thing happens, so its definitely a bug, I was planning on submitting a bug report just wanted to know if anyone had a workaround.